# Python-docx - check if text in table has hidden attribute applied

Tags: python, hidden, python-docx

I am new to Python and I am trying to check docx file for texts in table that have hidden attribute applied to them. If True, then I want to ignore that hidden text and replace any other text that matches my regex.

The thing is everything been good (replacement is working) until I added **if i.font.hidden == True:** condition thata seems to be incorrect.

**The error I am getting:**
*AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'font'*

**This is the code I have:**

```
for table in doc.tables:
        for row in table.rows:
            for cell in row.cells:
                for p in cell.paragraphs:
                        if True:
                            inline = p.runs
                            for i in range(len(inline)):
                                if True:
                                    if i.font.hidden == True:
                                        continue
                                    else:
                                        text = inline[i].text.replace(regx, 'Abcd')
                                           
                                        inline[i].text = text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to access runs by index; you can iterate those directly:

```
for table in doc.tables:
    for row in table.rows:
        for cell in row.cells:
            for p in cell.paragraphs:
                for run in p.runs:
                    if not run.font.hidden:
                        run.text = run.text.replace(regx, 'Abcd')
```

Comment: Thanks, it works as well. I have not noticed that this method saves time in executing but it is certainly simplersince there is a bit less code.

Answer (score 0):

in your case `i` is simply an integer as you are iterating over a list of integers.

I would guess you need something like:

```
if inline[i].font.hidden == True:
    *do stuff*
```